# JavaScriptSerializer. How to deserialize a string array from JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, javascriptserializer

This is the model I'm using to deserialize.

**C#**

```
public class Info
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the JSON I want to deserialize.

**JSON**

```
{
    "description" : "aeiou",
    "tags" : [ "a", "e", "i", "o" ]
}
```

When I try to deserealize the JSON object, It throws error. It works when I change the identifier from string[] to just string, but that's not the expected result. I also tried List and didn't work.

Comment: What is the error? How are you dessrializing it?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();` and `var result = js.Deserialize<Info>(json);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the class like this, don't forget to new up the list first

```
public class Info
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what happened, I used List<string> and didn't work. When I got your answer, I tried again and It worked. I gotta say you were right!, thanks so much :)

Comment: Don't forget to add the 'set;' bit!  That was a silly omission by me that cause a fault in deserialising...